# Square brackets in math mode without the bracket symbols

Tags: math-mode, brackets

Is there a way to typeset a square bracket without using the symbols [ and ]?

What I am looking for is like `\vert` instead of `|`.

Motivation is a need for a workaround in using LaTeX formulas inside Moodle wiki pages.
The latter use square brackets to start a new page (like [page-name]), and this functionality interferes with scripts processing LaTeX formulas (which otherwise are ok in Moodle HTML/wiki).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
\lbrack
\rbrack
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply add the following command to your preamble.tex file in case you are on a template or if you are doing it from scratch then:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\Bracket{\lbrack}{\rbrack}

\newcommand*{\Value}{\frac{1}{2}x^2}%
\begin{document}
    \[\Bracket{\Value}\]
\end{document}
```